# Laravel VueJs Apache Virtualhost, virtual host name not appearing in URL when Vue is displayed

Tags: php, laravel, apache, vue.js, virtualhost

I have a linux box running multiple Laravel apps.  Laravel works great having setup virtual host correctly.  However, when I launch into VueJS the virtual host is not showing in the routes or resources.

Example:  http://192.168.1.x/app1

Shows Laravel, login screen, I can log in.  Then I change to VueJS route and I get 404 not found and when I look at URL, there is no app:

http://192.168.1.x/asset/image.png

where it should be

http://192.168.1.x/app1/asset/imgage.png

or

http://192.168.1.x/api/name

should be

http://192.168.1./app1/api/name

This seems like a configuration issue I just have not been able to resolve.  Anyone run into this?  As I mentioned, the laravel pages all work great, it is when VueJs is being run.

Comment: Try changing your `APP_URL`in your `.env` file to `http://192.168.1.x/app1/`

Comment: Already there.  Had that set up from the beginnning.

Comment: When in chrome looking at console, the "app1" is missing from routes.  What is strange is that this works great on my local Mac... I am connecting remotely to a linux box trying to get this to work remotely.

Comment: Can you open `artisan tinker` and execute `asset('foo')`?

Comment: I see a green link with the correct url, that is, it includes "app1".  Is there a similar command to simulate or execute through VueJS?

Comment: Post your VueJS code, because there's nothing that indicates how you're using it in your question

Comment: <template>
<div>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
          <img src="/assets/app_logo.png" width="70" height="28">
        </a>

        <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

Comment: Ofc it won't work because / refers to the host, change the base_url for all links

Comment: yeah, the problem with that is that it doesn't propagate; that is, I would need separate code for my local development environment (i.e. mac) and separate code for the linux box.  I was hoping to have a single code base and simply adjust the environment.  Strange how Laravel works fine but VueJs does not.

Comment: is the 'Linux box'' your production environment?

Comment: it is in a lab running a couple of laravel apps.  Is it production... I guess you could say that.  I updated url references and it is working as expected.  But now my local dev and production are out of sync.  It is not a lot so just some manual effort.

Comment: What you can do is conditionally spit out the base url `@if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production')`

Comment: Ah, that's a good suggestion.  Thanks for all your help.  Very much appreciated.